How to avoid `PyBorrowMutError` when passing parent struct to python function, and calling mutable parent member
I've created the following directory structure:
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── pyproject.toml
├── python
│  └── main.py
└── src
   └── lib.rs

Where only lib.rs and main.py are custom made, the rest was generated by maturin init
lib.rs is :
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Float3{
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    x : f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    y : f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    z : f64,
}
#[pymethods]
impl Float3 {
    #[new]
    fn py_new(x : f64, y : f64, z : f64) -> Self {
        Float3 { x, y, z}
    }
}

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct ParentFloat3 {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    data: Vec<Float3>,
    python_functions :Vec<PyObject>,
}
#[pymethods]
impl ParentFloat3 {
    #[new]
    fn py_new(data : Vec<Float3>, python_functions : Vec<PyObject>) -> Self {
        ParentFloat3 {data, python_functions}
    }

    fn test_fn(slf : &Bound<'_, Self>) -> PyResult<i32>{
        for python_function in slf.borrow().python_functions.iter(){
            python_function.call1(slf.py(), (slf,))?;
        }
    Ok(10)
    }

    fn update_at<'py>(slf : &Bound<'_, Self>, idx :usize)  -> PyResult<()>{
        slf.borrow_mut().data[idx].x += 2.0f64;  
        return Ok(());
    }
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn test_pyo3(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Float3>()?; 
    m.add_class::<ParentFloat3>()?; 
    Ok(())
}

And main.py is:
import test_pyo3

def modify_parent_float_3(parent : test_pyo3.ParentFloat3):
    for i in range(4):
        parent.update_at(i)

def main():

    temp_float3s = test_pyo3.ParentFloat3([test_pyo3.Float3(0,0,0)] * 4, [modify_parent_float_3])
    print(temp_float3s.data[0].x)
    print(temp_float3s.data[0].x, temp_float3s.data[0].y, temp_float3s.data[0].z)
    temp_float3s.test_fn()
    print(temp_float3s.data[0].x, temp_float3s.data[0].y, temp_float3s.data[0].z)
    pass




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

output is:
0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at /path/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.21.2/src/pycell.rs:852:31:
Already borrowed: PyBorrowMutError
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
--- PyO3 is resuming a panic after fetching a PanicException from Python. ---
Python stack trace below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/test_pyo3/python/main.py", line 5, in modify_parent_float_3
    parent.update_at(i)
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Already borrowed: PyBorrowMutError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/test_pyo3/python/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/path/test_pyo3/python/main.py", line 12, in main
    temp_float3s.test_fn()
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Already borrowed: PyBorrowMutError

How do I avoid this PyBorrowMut error?  I believe it's comming from the fact that I'm doing this:
    fn test_fn(slf : &Bound<'_, Self>) -> PyResult<i32>{
        for python_function in slf.borrow().python_functions.iter(){
            python_function.call1(slf.py(), (slf,))?;
        }
    Ok(10)
    }

Which borrows immutably self (same happens when mutably borrowing), then passing self to python function which then calls this member function on self:
    fn update_at<'py>(slf : &Bound<'_, Self>, idx :usize)  -> PyResult<()>{
        slf.borrow_mut().data[idx].x += 2.0f64;  
        return Ok(());
    }

Which borrows mutably.  I don't know how to get PyO3 to recognize that it's the same borrow, or even skirt this using unsafe, I can get "as_ptr()", but I don't know how to go from a mut* ffi::PyObject to my class's type ParentFloat3 again to avoid borrowing (since it's not a normal raw pointer) to avoid borrow issues.
I also tried using Py<T>, and it came up with the same error:
fn update_at<'py>(slf : &Bound<'_, Self>, idx :usize)  -> PyResult<()>{
    let temp_slf = slf.as_unbound(); 
    let new_ref = Py::clone_ref(&temp_slf, slf.py());
    new_ref.borrow_mut(slf.py()).data[idx].x += 2.0f64;  
    return Ok(());
}

I don't want solutions that involve wild overhead (copying), or requiring me to change the actual data structure of my class (using PyList instead of Vec etc...) as the actual code needs to be python agnostic.  Unsafe methods are fine.
Related: How to modify rust types passed to python which were initially created in python from Pyo3

You need to release the borrow when calling:
fn test_fn(slf: &Bound<'_, Self>) -> PyResult<i32> {
    let len = slf.borrow().python_functions.len();
    for i in 0..len {
        let python_function = slf.borrow().python_functions[i].clone_ref(slf.py());
        python_function.call1(slf.py(), (slf,))?;
    }
    Ok(10)
}


can you elaborate how the borrowing works here? So clone_ref just copies the python reference and not the actual object here, and the borrow is per reference to the object?

@Krupip clone_ref() increases the Python reference count. The key is that while we call the function we aren't holding the borrow. For that, we borrow, get the function, clone it, release the borrow, then call the function.
